# Create nested object dynamically with forEach

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have an 'path' string: `'profile.name.en'`;

I want to use this to create an object dynamically. I'm using this function and its working:

```
function set(obj, path, value) {
    var schema = obj;  // a moving reference to internal objects within obj
    var arr = path.split('.');
    var len = arr.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < len-1; i++) {
        var elem = arr[i];
        if( !schema[elem] ) schema[elem] = {};
        schema = schema[elem];
    }
    schema[arr[len-1]] = value;
    return schema;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var a = {};
var path = 'profile.name.en';
var profileName = 'OleFrank';
var o = set(a, path, profileName);

// result
{
    profile: {
        name: {
            en: 'OleFrank'
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to refactor to using forEach instead of for-loop, but then it's not working anymore. Why is this??

Comment: Show us your forEach attempt.

Comment: May caused by lexical scoping...

Comment: why forEach? reduce would fit better.

Comment: `.forEach()` won't `return` anything in case you tried like in your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), because this returns the object you need, without keeping a reference outside.

```js
function set(object, path, value) {
    var keys = path.split('.'),
        last = keys.pop();

    keys.reduce(function (o, k) {
        return o[k] = o[k] || {};
    }, object)[last] = value;
}

var a = {},
    path = 'profile.name.en',
    profileName = 'OleFrank';

set(a, path, profileName); // no need of an assignment, because of
                           // call by reference with an object

console.log(a);
```

Version with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
function set(object, path, value) {
    var keys = path.split('.'),
        last = keys.pop();

    keys.forEach(function (k) {
        object[k] = object[k] || {};
        object = object[k];
    });
    object[last] = value;
}

var a = {},
    path = 'profile.name.en',
    profileName = 'OleFrank';

set(a, path, profileName);

console.log(a);
```